# As soon as structure: save/ saved/ have saved?

Tags: grammar

I'm currently very confused about the structures of 'As soon as'. There are three sentences that I can't decide which is gramatically correct.

> As soon as I save enough money, I'll get a new bicycle.

And

> As soon as I saved enough money, I'll get a new bicycle.

And

> As soon as I have saved enough money, I'll get a new bicycle.

Also, I do need examples about 'as soon as' sentences. Like how tenses can fit in with 'as soon as', please give me as much as tenses with this 'as soon as' as you could. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Because there is a period of time when using "as soon as" (from now until you have all the money), use present perfect "have saved". But rather than ask for "as soon as" examples, you should search for some and then ask about what you don't understand.

Comment: Both the first and third are fine. But the second doesn't work because it mixes past and future inappropriately.